# elFinder after close won't show again

Tags: php, jquery-ui, file-manager

I have a little problem with elFinder. I'll try to explain the best I can.

When I click the button to open elfinder it opens and let me do the work without any problem. The thing is when I try to open it again, without reloading the page it won't show again.
But if I reload the page I can open it again just for one time, then I have the same problem.

Other thing is that the menu bar is not showing, but when i try to inspect the Network transitions, and images loaded there aren't any failure.

I leave a link to the images of the first time I open it and the second one.

[First time i open it](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/1sttimeg.jpg/)

[Second time i open it](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/2ndtime.jpg/)

PS: Sorry about the wrong tags, but I can't create an elFinder one because my rating is still to low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find out what was the problem and what is the solution(not yet implemented).
The problem is that i was trying to create an elfinder instance for the second time instead of just open the first one  i created. The solution passes to check if there is an instance of elFinder already opened and use the following code, for example:

```
$('#elfinderdiv').elfinder('open');
```

Regards,
Elkas